# Responsive functionality for Calendar, does it exist?

Tags: calendar

Has anyone integrated calendar into a responsive template?

Comment: If you are having specific problems then please outline what they are here. Although it sounds like this could be more of a CSS question than an ExpressionEngine one.

Comment: There is no "responsive functionality". As with most EE add-ons Calendar just outputs data and makes no layout decisions for you. It's up to you to create a template that works responsively using the tags that Calendar provides.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more about html/css, but not about EE.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use the cal tag. If you click on view calendar events on [this page](http://www.seerockcity.com/events/entry/summer-music-weekends), that is a Solspace calendar that is responsive. The cal tags allow you to do this easily, it's all just css.